# splitting a float into fractions and integrals using C

Tags: c, floating-point

```
int decimalSplit(float f)
{   
    char s_value[60], s_integral[60], s_fractional[60];
    int i, found = 0, count = 1, integral, fractional;

    sprintf(s_value, "%f", f);

    for (i = 0; s_value[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (!found)
        {
            if (s_value[i] == '.')
            {
                found = 1;
                s_integral[i] = '\0';
                continue;
            }
            s_integral[i] = s_value[i];
            count++;
        }
        else
        s_fractional[i - count] = s_value[i];
    }
    s_fractional[i - count] = '\0';

    integral = atoi(s_integral);
    fractional = atoi(s_fractional);

    return integral;
}
```

Hello, I am trying to make a program which splits a float number into integral part(as int) and fractional part(as int). It would be also a QoL upgrade for me if the program stores these in an array and returns that array.(In the example code the implementation returns only one integer.)
For example, 682.1 should return, 682 and 1.(in an array preferably) I want my program to find "." in the given argument, make a new integer from integrals and make another integer from fractions.

At online IDE's my code works, however on my atmel solution I get "conflicting types for "Decimalsplit" error. I'd like to hear from you about where the problem is.

Comment: What do you want `682.01` to give? The same as `682.1`?

Comment: I want my code to give 682 and 01.

Comment: But as an integer, `01` and `1` are the same. Are you _sure_ you want to represent the fractional part as an integer?

Comment: **Always** (yes, always) prefer `double` over `float`.

Comment: what about `2.99999999999420125`?

Comment: It is impossible to pass 682.1 as a `float` in C implementations that use a binary-based floating-point, as 682.1 cannot be represented exactly in a binary-based format. In the format most commonly used for `float`, the closest representable value is 682.0999755859375. So a function that truly returned the fraction part as an integer would return 682 and 999755859375. Is that what you want? Why or why not? What do you need this function for?

Comment: Re “on my atmel solution I get "conflicting types for "Decimalsplit" error”: This is caused by failing to declare the function before using it. One problem may be that the function definition you show here is `decimalSplit` but the error message shows you are trying to call it as `Decimalsplit`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was writing a driver for 4 digit 7 segment display. I have written a completel differenty driver based on a completely different logic  to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> program [...] returns [...] array

*quote heavily edited*

You can wrap the array in a struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Arr2 { int data[2]; };

struct Arr2 foo(double x) {
    struct Arr2 r;
    r.data[0] = x;
    r.data[1] = (x - r.data[0]) * 1000000;
    return r;
}

int main(void) {
    struct Arr2 split;
    split = foo(3.14159);
    printf("%d + 0.%06d\n", split.data[0], split.data[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/NmTvxn